# Ito's formula but not given $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have a little question from one of my worksheets(the solution I was given was almost not even a solution, super brief).

> let $f(t,x)=t\cos(x)$. Use Ito's formula to calculate $df(t,W_t)$.

Well, Ito's formula is $df=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2})dt + \sigma \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dW_t$ if I am correct. I can calculate each partial derivative wrp to $f$ but what of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?Do I just leave them as some constant which is unknown?

The solutions simply gives me the derivatives and then it only says "Now apply Ito's formula" and over. Doesn't show me the final result/answer as to what $df$ becomes under Ito.

Can someone tell me if there is a way to find $\mu$ $\sigma$ given only $f$? Or do I really just leave it like so.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itô's formula, as you've written it, is to compute $df(t, X_t)$ where $X_t$ is a process satisfying $dX_t = \sigma\, dW_t + \mu \,dt$.

So in your case, take $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$, so that $X_t = W_t$.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering; as this will sound very elementary, I am slightly wondering, so, the $\mu$ $\sigma$  are mean/variance of the process $f(t, \text{"whatever process is in here"})$? So I take $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ because that process now is $W_t$(Brownian)? Or does this have nothing to do with that but just because $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ would allow $X_t=W_t$?

Comment: @JohnTrail: Yeah, that's basically right.  If $\mu, \sigma$ are constants then $X_t$ is a Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  (Note that $\mu,\sigma$ don't directly describe the mean/variance of $f(t,X_t)$, though.) They could also be non-constant adapted processes, but that's not what you want here.

Comment: I see thanks! That clarified quite a lot in a very short answer, appreciate it much :)